# Software to create video tutorial of mathematics topics

Tags: technology-in-education, tutoring, software

I came across many video tutorials on youtube regarding mathematics.
I found [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uD4lJlfPn-0) video amazingly simple to understand for students.
I want to know about the tool/software used for it or similar videos.

Screenshots:

1)

[image]

2)

[image]

Youtube Video:

copy `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uD4lJlfPn-0` or [click here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uD4lJlfPn-0)

please feel free to provide your suggestions which may have better options

Thanks

Comment: One free but slightly restricted alternative to look at is the tablet app/web-based [educreations.com](http://www.educreations.com/).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I've created roughly 40 videos for an online course and a flipped course in biology, so I've got some experience making videos. I researched the maker of your videos, and he deliberately does NOT reveal his process. So I don't *know* if this is his method, but I'm comfortable that this would produce something very similar.

Supplies:

1. Computer (I use a Windows 7 machine, but Mac should work) with a decent mic
2. Presentation software (I use PowerPoint) that has a plain "graph paper" background option
3. Wacom-style tablet, about $200
4. Screencast software like [Camtasia Studio](http://www.techsmith.com/camtasia.html), about $200
5. Calculator emulator software. TI makes a $160 one, but [this one](http://www.studentcalculators.co.uk/acatalog/copy_of_software.html) looks like the one your YouTube guy uses.

Then, his workflow is to build up a powerpoint show with some drawings already made and set to appear when he clicks. He starts the screen cast, narrates, and draws in where needed. He can alt-tab the calculator onto the screen when he wants it (or set it as a picture-in-picture? I've never used one). 
After completing the recording, some writing can be speeded up as long as you aren't talking during that part. Export, upload to YouTube.

All you need is money, time, some drawing skill, and the ability to be clear and concise and brisk.

Have I missed any steps?

Comment: That's almost exactly the same sort of toolchain I use, especially Camtasia Studio which is excellent and wipes the floor with free alternatives I've used. I use a (casio) calculator emulator with alt-tab or click - picture in picture is unnecessary. I use software that came with our interactive whiteboard and preprepare like you say. My old toshiba stylus-tablet screen laptop or an interactive whiteboard are my favourite hardware - personally I find screenless tablets hard to be tidy on, but that might just be me.

Comment: I use a fujitsu tablet laptop, but I mostly circle and arrow, I don't write things out.  I need to improve my drawing skills....

Comment: I did some (a bit) similar videos.  I went for the "budget" version: Linux (which I use almost exclusively anyway), Kdenlive (which is not *very* good, but enough for me), and LaTeX+Beamer for creating slides (and ImageMagick for converting the pdfs to bitmaps, then included in Kdenlive).  Please note that what I did was mostly videocasts, not screencasts, though I'll try screencasts soon, too.

Comment: Of course, while this answers the question, this is just ONE approach to doing it. The other method involves composing your presentation in something like Vegas/Final Cut/Premier/open-source-equivalent and syncing animations with audio you record from a script. They both have their advantages; I think the post-com method tends to come off as more polished, but it also requires a lot more work for what is probably questionable benefit.

Answer (score 9):

Here are some tools that can be used for creating high quality Maths video lessons:

**Hardware**

1. Computer with tablet, or just a tablet computer (e.g. Microsoft Surface Pro 3).
2. External microphone of a reasonably high quality. I use the Blue Yeti which seems to be a good compromise between quality and price. Previously I used a Logitech Headset which I found frustrating because it would pick up unwanted sounds, and generally made things too quiet.

**Software**

1. Some sort of screen capturing software. Most people seem to think that [Camtasia Studio](http://www.techsmith.com/camtasia.html) is the best for recording and subsequent editing. If you are creating shorter videos and don't require editing there are free options around.
2. A program which allows you to write and draw. My preference here is OneNote as it seems to use the pressure-sensitivity of tablet computers and make handwriting look neat.
3. Optionally, a program to record the audio separately like [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/), and you then synchronise your recorded script with the video. This method requires decent editing software, like Camtasia Studio, mentioned above.

**Mathematics specific software**

1. [Desmos](http://desmos.com/calculator/) is an excellent web-based program that allows you to create graphs and animate them. This is a great way to create animations.
2. A calculator-emulator (possibly just web-based). I've found typing 'calculator' into Google and using the built-in one is sufficient for my purposes.

**EDIT: Some sample videos created with setup described above**

1. [A video on dilation/reflection](https://vimeo.com/humberstone/dilation) with animations created using Desmos and handwritten portions created in OneNote.
2. [A video on the unit circle](https://vimeo.com/humberstone/unitcircle) again with animations created using Desmos.
3. [A video on sin and cos graphs](https://vimeo.com/humberstone/sincosgraphs) showing the use of multiple video tracks, one with the Unit Circle showing and one for the graph itself. This is the first one I recorded using the Blue Yeti microphone.
4. [An earlier video on factorising quadratics](https://vimeo.com/humberstone/factorising) created just using Camtasia and OneNote. This was before I realised that better quality videos are created by recording the audio separately from the video. (The physical constraints of handwriting means that such videos feel a lot slower, whereas in other videos I generally speed up my writing to about double speed.)

Comment: I second the Desmos appreciation. I created several animations for DEqns last semester. Literally cut and paste solutions tinker for a couple minutes and it came out better than anything I could create in Maple or Mathematica in an hour.

Answer (score 4):

3blue1brown makes the best math videos in existence in my opinion, and he uses a Python library called [manim](https://github.com/3b1b/manim).

Answer (score 2):

I haven't made any video's in wich my face appears on the screen (on purpose). 
I also haven't done many video's in wich i explain things and not even that many in general. 
However i have made a few short video's to motivate my students, aged roughly 12-16. When making these motivational video's i simply create images by placing different pictures and texts over eachother using simply Paint, Windows moviemaker , Word or PIXLR (free 'photoshop' online software).

It's very time consuming at first but you get faster at it.
Sometimes it really gets the pupils exited and therefor it's usually been worth the effort.

(For an example of the video's i made : https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCio66FwDtvZnm7puStBV7ow )

Answer (score 0):

A relatively simple way is to **record a Zoom presentation by/to yourself**.

- create a new Zoom meeting,
- then "share screen" of the screen you want to record (e.g. window on your laptop, or your tablet screen),
- hit record (in Zoom) and start presenting

(My answer addresses the question in the title, not the aspect about TI-calculators, which I don't use).

Answer (score 0):

Modern Windows systems come with an "xbox game capture" which is pretty generous about what it considers a game, including allowing you to capture ms paint and web browsers.

You can move up from that to OBS Studio, which is free and allows you to combine/crop video sources and switch between scenes (configurations of combined/cropped video sources) at record time.

If you're interested in making your own videos I definitely suggest practicing with software/hardware that's free or that you already have available before spending money.

Answer (score 0):

It is also well worth checking out the very powerful and entirely free [Open Broadcaster Software](https://obsproject.com/).  Available on all three operating systems.