# Software / hardware for creating Khan Academy style videos?

Tags: software

What software and/or hardware is typically used for creating Khan Academy style math videos?

Comment: i think this question has potential but i am going to edit it to make it less subjective so it has a better chance of not being closed

Comment: Related: http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/2279/software-to-create-video-tutorial-of-mathematics-topics

Comment: @DagOskarMadsen Thanks, my question is a duplicate of that one.  This question should be closed as duplicate.

Comment: My college uses [Panopto](http://panopto.com/panopto-for-education/). It is easy to use, but I cannot compare it to other software.