# Software and techniques for creating short maths animation videos for kids

Tags: technology-in-education, tutoring, software

I am a teacher and want to start on online website with videos to make work easy for both parents and teachers in mathematics for children. I saw this video and was wondering if someone could help me identify the software or techniques or better still tools used.

https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=Mphoweh+Jude+Nzembayie

Please feel free to provide your suggestions which may have better options.

Thanks.

Comment: I prefer Geogebra: you can draw graphs and geometrical shapes in quite a nice way.

Comment: See also https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/2279/376

Answer (score 1):

Maybe start here:
[The Top 6 Animated Video Software In The eLearning Market](https://elearningindustry.com/the-top-6-animated-video-software-in-the-elearning-market):

1. GoAnimate
2. CrazyTalk
3. iClone
4. Toon Boom Harmony
5. After Effects
6. PowToon

Few of these are free; the link above gives pricing. Here is a PowToon image:

---

[image: PowToon]

---

For totally free software, search for "free software to make simple educational animations."

Answer (score 0):

I personally started to make Math videos early this year with a Mac. My videos look a bit "rustic" because they are mostly hand-drawn, but they have some character and I think that makes them interesting (similar to an XKCD comic if you're familiar with that).

I use Microsoft OneNote (a free application) to write within. I use a Wacom Tablet (like $80) for writing on the screen (You hold a pen and OneNote records what you're doing. It is pressure sensitive too, which gives the writing a nice realistic quality).

I use software called "Movavi Screen Capture 4" to record what I'm writing. (Mac has a free screen capture included with Quicktime but Movavi lets you set a specific resolution, which I've found useful).

Finally, I will edit in "Final Cut Pro". (This is definitely optional and a bit of a cost/time expenditure). I bought an external Microphone to increase the quality of my voice as well.

The end result isn't a professional as what you're looking at, but it allows you to relatively quickly make a video to get some point across, which I think is extremely beneficial to students since they can watch/rewatch/rewind on their own time whenever they want.